# Codeigniter active record query only rows with first letter is not an alphabet

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to write an active record statement where I will be able to get all rows in the database where the first letter is not equal to an alphabet.

This is my active record query

```
$this->db->where("employer_name NOT LIKE '[^a-z]%'");
return $this->db->select()->from("v_employers")->get();
```

the problem with my code is that it gets everything in my database

i only want to get rows where the first letter is not an alphabet

ex(123pencil,$helloworld,7eleven)

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex in the where clause

```
WHERE `employer_name` REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z].*$'
```

Full query:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM v_employers WHERE `employer_name` REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z].*$'");
```

Comment: tried both and it still shows alphabetic letters
did i write it correctly?

$this->db->where("employer_name NOT LIKE '^[a-zA-Z].*$'");

return $this->db->select()->from("v_employers")->get();

Comment: @itsover9000 try this syntax